# Layout can't be found

Tags: android, android-layout

When I use the following line :

```
LinearLayout layoutRoot = (LinearLayout) findViewById (R.id.layoutRoot);
```

it gives an error saying that `R.id.layoutRoot cannot be resolved.`

what does it mean?

Comment: Can you show us the exact error that you get as well as where in the code you are calling setContentView()?

Comment: View content = findViewById(R.layout.layoutRoot);
        Bitmap bitmap = content.getDrawingCache();                                             This is the code and basically i want to take a screen shot and save it.

Answer (score 1):

Verify that in your imports, you have something like:

```
import com.myproject.R
```

and not

```
import android.R
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your `R.java file` (which is in the *gen* directory) and you will see that the layouts identifiants don't belong to the `id` class but the `layout` class.

```
    public static final class id {

    }
    public static final class layout {
        // Layouts are here...
    }
```

So it should be: `R.layout.layoutRoot`.

Comment: I looked into the layout class ,it deosnt have the layoutroot in it

Comment: Do you really have a layout called layoutRoot.xml then?

Answer (score 0):

Save the project
Exclude bin, gen from svn (if you use it)
Commit, update (if you use svn)
Clean

try to build again. If won't work:

Delete gen, bin
Save

Build.